# I want to make a have a datepicker(calendar) to filter my database record base on timestamps (Laravel 6)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, datepicker

How to add a date picker for my reports data (Laravel6)
I still have no idea on where to start.

Here is my  report controller(index):

```
  public function index()
{
    $reports=Report::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

    return view('reports.index',['reports' => $reports]);
}
```

Here is my index on my report.index html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Student number</th>
                            <th scope="col">Transaction</th>
                            <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
                            <th scope="col">Queue number</th>
                            <th scope="col">Created at</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach ($reports as $report)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $report->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $report->snumber}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $report->transaction}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $report->remarks}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $report->letter}}-{{ $report->number}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $report->created_at }}</td>

                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer py-4">
                    <nav class="d-flex justify-content-end" aria-label="...">
                        {{ $reports->links() }}
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

My database table look like this:

```
 Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('snumber');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('department');
        $table->string('letter');
        $table->integer('number');
        $table->string('transaction');
        $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To filter your data first you have to put your `datepicker` within `form` tag outside of your table which contains data.

If you want to use ajax call then pass that form value which contains filter date and in same `index` method you can check that this call is ajax call or not.

If ajax call then override variable with filtered data.

Something like this,

```
$reports=Report::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
if($request->ajax()){
        $reports=Report::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->whereDate('created_at', today())->paginate(10);
}
return view('reports.index',['reports' => $reports]);
```

if you dont want to use ajax call and want to load page, then you can pass the data and check that it exist or not, something like this,

```
$reports=Report::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->when(! empty(\request('filterdate')), function($q) {
    return $q->whereDate('created_at', today());
})
->paginate(10);
return view('reports.index',['reports' => $reports]);
```

It will only filter date when `filterdate` is not empty.

Hope this helps :)